# remove services text from pixel splash screen

Tags: boot, pixel

I have followed instructions i have found here to get rid of most boot text but while the custom splashscreen in pixel is displayed i'm getting a list of services showing up.  how do i hide that

Comment: This is not nearly enough information to answer your question. You'll have to be more specific about what you did and why it doesn't work.

Comment: i modified the cmdline and got rid of messages there by changing log level and tty and such.  i no longer get any messages till pixel loads splash.png from /usr/share/plymouth/themes/pix or wherever that was.  don't have the pi in front of me.  while it is displaying the splash screen it also displays all the .service things that run.  that is what i'm trying to get rid of

Answer (score 5):

Just remove the last lines within the /usr/share/plymouth/themes/pix/pix.script file or comment them out:

```
#message_sprite = Sprite();
#message_sprite.SetPosition(screen_width * 0.1, screen_height * 0.9, 10000);
#
#fun message_callback (text) {
#       my_image = Image.Text(text, 1, 1, 1);
#       message_sprite.SetImage(my_image);
#       sprite.SetImage (resized_image);
#}
#
#Plymouth.SetUpdateStatusFunction(message_callback);
```

This should remove the text as required.